# How to extract receive message body from XMPPMessage?

Tags: swift, xmppframework

I get all messages sent to me from all users.
 When I get the result it is type of XMPPMessage, I don't know how to extract body from this

> This problem is related to get archived messages.

```
func getALLMessagesFromServerWithXML() {
    let query = try? XMLElement(xmlString: "<query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:2'/>")
    let iq = XMLElement.element(withName: "iq") as? XMLElement
    iq?.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "set")
    iq?.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: "getAllMesseges")
    if let aQuery = query {
        iq?.addChild(aQuery)
    }

    xmppStream.send(iq!)
}
```

The result is gotten from  this method:

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive message: XMPPMessage) {
    print(message)
}
```

### Output

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" to="f.talebi@x/1516292205485357040111042" from="f.talebi@x"><result xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:2" id="1530957470465122"><forwarded xmlns="urn:xmpp:forward:0"><message xmlns="jabber:client" lang="en" to="a.mardani@xmpp.x.ir" from="f.talebi@x.ir/134788006381643425047394" type="chat"><archived xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:tmp" by="f.talebi@x.ir" id="1530957470465122"></archived><stanza-id xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0" by="f.talebi@x.ir" id="1530957470465122"></stanza-id><body>hi 2018-07-07 09:57:49 +0000</body></message><delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="x.ir" stamp="2018-07-07T09:57:50.465122Z"></delay></forwarded></result></message>
```

How can I extract body from this output? for normal messages I can get body by `message.body` but for the archived messages I cannot get body with this code.

According to @andesta.erfan answer, I added these codes:

variable:

```
private var archiving = XMPPMessageArchiveManagement()
```

in init()

```
archiving = XMPPMessageArchiveManagement(dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
archiving?.activate(xmppStream)    
archiving?.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

Extension implementation:

```
extension XMPPHelper: XMPPMessageArchiveManagementDelegate {

    func xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_ xmppMessageArchiveManagement: XMPPMessageArchiveManagement, didReceiveMAMMessage message: XMPPMessage) {
        print(message.body())
    }

}
```

But xmppMessageArchiveManagement is never called, `xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive message: XMPPMessage)` is called in both situation. when it is an archived message or the normal one.

Comment: Try to print : message.body, don't know in your case you access (message.body), because it depends on code. or try this - NSString *str = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];

Comment: use `mam:1` instead of `mam:2`

Answer (score 3):

for regular message you should use:

`func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive message: XMPPMessage) {
    print(message.body())
}`

for MAM purposes you should implement XmppMessageArchiveManagement and it,s delegate.one of it's delegate method is this:

`func xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_ xmppMessageArchiveManagement: XMPPMessageArchiveManagement, didReceiveMAMMessage message: XMPPMessage) {
        print(message.body)
    }`

you can print the archive one with that.
be aware that your outgoing packet should be something like this:

```
`let value = DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: jid)
 let child = DDXMLElement(name: "field")
 child.addChild(value)
 child.addAttribute(withName: "var", stringValue: "with")
 let set = XMPPResultSet(max: 1, before: "")
 XmppMessageArchiveModule.retrieveMessageArchive(at: nil, withFields: [child], with: set)`
```

`max: 1` tell the MAM that you want only the last Message for specific jid.
after doing all that please please check this answer [[service unavailable error in openfire message archive management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237997/service-unavailable-error-in-openfire-message-archive-management/51240636?noredirect=1#comment89464395_51240636])

Comment: Thanks, bus this can be used for normal messages not the archived one.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. I did what you said but xmppMessageArchiveManagement is never called.

Comment: @FattanehTalebi please see my another answer in here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237997/service-unavailable-error-in-openfire-message-archive-management/51240636?noredirect=1#comment89464395_51240636].you are using mam:2 and if your server is openfire it does not support and you should use mam:1

Comment: I checked this, unfortunately it didn't work. I get archived messages but I get them in xmppStream method not in xmppMessageArchiveManagement method.

Comment: hi @andesta.erfan I try this code to get chat history but its not working. pls see this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749713/issue-on-retrieve-the-xmpp-archived-message-from-ejabberd-serverchat-history) and share your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

```
 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
    {
        NSString *str = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

**XMPPStreamDelegate**

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive message: XMPPMessage) {
     let body = message.body
}
```

**XMPPMessageArchiveManagementDelegate**

```
func xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_ xmppMessageArchiveManagement: XMPPMessageArchiveManagement, didReceiveMAMMessage message: XMPPMessage) {
  if let xmppMessage = message.mamResult?.forwardedMessage {
     let body = xmppMessage.body
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share/provide any project link like GitHub? I am facing difficulties with core data management using XMPP.